# DIY Bluetooth speaker

Tags: amplifier, sound, watts

This is my first project.

I have two 2 ohm, 12 W speakers. I need a very good quality sound amplifier with Bluetooth if possible.

Is the PAM8610 good in terms of sound quality?

Can someone suggest an amplifier?

Comment: This is a question asking for recommendation / opinion, and is off-topic for EE. Read more about what questions to ask, at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The [PAM8610](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/PAM8610.pdf) datasheet contains **NOT RECOMMENDED FOR NEW DESIGN
USE [PAM8006A](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8006A.pdf)**. So, if this is for a new design consider using a later device.

Comment: How do you define a very good quality amplifier? Specifications with actual numbers are required and some amplifiers either meet or don't meet your specification for a good amplifier.

Comment: I don't think chip amps qualify as "very good quality". Some folks wouldn't consider any class D "very good quality", but these days, you'll be hard-pressed to find top-shelf DIY modules, so give it a listen and see if it's acceptable. It's not like bluetooth even provides for hi-fi anyway, so you amp isn't the only bottleneck.

Comment: You can consider TPA3116D2 Bluetooth Amplifier Board. It offers good sound quality and the convenience of Bluetooth connectivity.